# How to make these divs responsive

Tags: css

I am new to web development and so to Stackoverflow.
I am stuck at changing `width` to make it responsive.

Below, I have got this example that's meant to be explaining the property `background-blend-mode`. After I finished with it I wanted to use it as a refresher to previous lessons. I wanted to style it to make it responsive in terms of changing the `max` and `min` `width` properties.

```css
div {
  width: 280px;
  height: 140px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: green url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/13090/colorful-heart.png) no-repeat center 0;
  background-size: contain;
}

.multiply {
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div>
</div>
<div class="multiply">
</div>
</html>
```

What happens is when the viewport's width (at Chrome) changes to **less** **than** 740px the divs display as `block` element. When I got to use the`box-sizing`property to set its value to `border-box`it changed the break point to 620px instead of 740px which means that any `width` under 620px makes the `div`s still display as `block` elements.


What I am  stuck at is set a **responsive** viewport for these divs so they are always displayed as `inline` elements, no matter what viewport's width is.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check this one**

```css
div {
  width: 280px;
  height: 140px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: green url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/13090/colorful-heart.png) no-repeat center 0;
  background-size: contain;
}

.multiply {
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    text-align: center;
  }
  div {
    width: 48%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 15px 0;
    padding: 13% 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class="multiply"></div>
```

Comment: Fantastic! That really did what I've been trying to do. Thank you. Could you please explain to me the `div` part in the third rule-set ? Why did you code it that way.

Comment: Also, why did you make your `max-width` 767px instead of 740px? Thanks

Comment: It's not fixed , mainly i use this media querry.
And this also a common and standard querry.

Comment: Well done! Are you able to explain why you used specific max-width of 767px, and how you calculated the `width` of the `div`in `media` to be 48%, `margin` 15px 0, and `padding` of 13%? I'd appreciate it if you managed to elaborate it. Thanks.

Comment: `max-width of 767px` it's not a fixed value you can change the value. The reason i use this value is it's a standard media querry value for mobile device. And i use this commonly.The other is to make you work responsive in less than 767px.

Answer (score 0):

Try it. I have added some css and media query for responsive.

```css
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  list-style:none;
}
html {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.common {
  width: 340px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: green url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/13090/colorful-heart.png) no-repeat center 0;
  background-size: contain;
}

.multiply {
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
  .common{
    width:45%;
    height:auto;
    margin: 10px auto 10px;
    padding: 14%;
  }
  .wrap{
    text-align:center;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="common"></div>
    <div class="common multiply"></div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Unfortunately, it did't achieve what I desired. The `div` elements (the 2 hearts) stay `inline` but breakpoint on 767px under and change to display the divs as `block` elements

Comment: Sorry I understood wrong. I have updated my code. Please check it.

Comment: That really worked too but with more coding. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of responsive do you want? Responsive really just means responds to -- the screen size. So the behavior is really up to you. From exactly what I'm seeing you have two options.

Responsive in just the width. This means that as you scale down to smaller than the two block size they'll scale down width wise only. To achieve this you set you max-width to `280px` then because you have two objects you want to set the width to `50%`. The problem with this is at some point you'll end up with very narrow blocks.

```
div {
  max-width: 280px;
  height: 140px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: green url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/13090/colorful-heart.png) no-repeat center 0;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 50%;
}

.multiply {
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6fjcoxmt/4/

Responsive in aspect radio. The other option is keeping the aspect ratio where you need to use a technique with an pseudo element that holds the parent's aspect ratio. You still need to use the technique from 1. but it gets a bit more complicated. Your element's wrapper will need to control the aspect ratio.

```
<div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="multiply">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Notice now `.inner` was your previous element's visual and the parent div will focus on controlling the height to width ratio:

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  max-width: 280px;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 58.8%;
}

.multiply .inner {
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}

.inner {
  background: green url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/13090/colorful-heart.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6fjcoxmt/16/

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough with my issue. Anzil khaN managed to get it sorted. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: I didn't want to add any extra coding in the HTML or any styles to it but the style that can utilise the  `min-width` or `max-width`.

Comment: I tried your coding but the view port breaks when the viewport changes from 619px and under, and display the divs as `block` elements.